# Is there any way to add my progress bar always just below the "Add To Cart" button on shopify for each theme

Tags: php, jquery, shopify

I have to add a progress bar always exact below the "Add To Cart" button, I am adding it using script tag. But for each theme the id and class of the "Add To Cart" button is vary. So any possible solution for that. Also can i load bootstrap via script tag. currently i am using inline style for my progress bar.
The "Add To Cart" button for first theme is

```
<form id="AddToCartForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/cart/add">
    <button class="btn" id="AddToCart" name="add" type="submit">
        <span id="AddToCartText">Add to Cart</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

and for the second theme is

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/cart/add">

  <div id="product-add">
    <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="primary button" id="add" name="add">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using javascript and api you can add progress bar. Try to use element class insted of id. -j()t